# Do we have $\lVert f\rVert_{L^p(X)}=\int_0^\infty p\alpha^{p-1}d_f(\alpha)\,\mathrm{d}\alpha$ for non $\sigma$-finite $X$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, weak-lp-spaces

Recall that for $\sigma$-finite measure spaces $(X,\mathscr{M},\mu)$, for any measurable function $f:X\to\mathbb{C}$, we can recover $\lVert f\rVert_{L^p(X)}$ by defining the distribution function $d_f(\alpha)=\mu(\{\lvert f\rvert>\alpha\})$ and using Fubini-Tonelli to obtain that $$\lVert f\rVert_{L^p(X)}=\int_0^\infty p\alpha^{p-1}d_f(\alpha)\,\mathrm{d}\alpha.$$

Does this remain true if $X$ is no longer $\sigma$-finite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that if $f \in L^p(X)$ then the set $\{|f| > 0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Suppose that $f$ is not in $L^p$. Then is the R.H.S. infinite?

Comment: Well, if the R.H.S. is finite, then $\{|f| > 0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite. Does that get you anywhere?

Comment: But $\{\lvert f\rvert>0\}$ can be $\sigma$-finite for $f$ not in $L^p$.

Comment: Sure it can, but see if you can work it out from here.

Comment: How can I prove the above assuming $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite? Which means I cannot use Fubini.

Comment: @adenamsn Are you asking how to show that $\{|f|>0\}$ is $\sigma$-finite?